# Encrypted Data not writing to file?

Tags: cocoa, encryption, nsdata, writetofile

In an encryption tool I am nearly finished with, I can't seem to write the encrypted data to a file.

Here is what I have:

```
    NSData *encryptedData = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:key];


    [encryptedData writeToFile:@"~/Desktop/file.txt" atomically:YES];
```

If 'file.txt' is not found, it should create it.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `-writeToFile:atomically:` is the name of the method you are trying to use-- not, as you have written, `-writeToFile:automatically:`. And second, this method should usually be avoided in favor of one that takes an out NSError parameter.

Try `-writeToFile:options:error:` if you'd like to be able to log a useful diagnostic when something goes wrong.

Comment: Wow, that was extremely stupid of me... Thank you. and I'll try the method that handles the error.

Comment: Not at all… It's an easy mistake to make. You may also want to ensure that the path automatically expands '~' for you, as normally that's something the shell does. (If it doesn't you can use the NSString method `-stringByExpandingTildeInPath` to DTRT.)

Comment: Thank you Kaelin, I will try that out.